R-W Metric and null geodesic path of photon
I was reading through Introduction to Cosmology, on Chapter 3, it gives me the R-W Metric:
$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2+a(t)^2[dr^2+{S_κ}(r)^2dΩ^2]$
${S_κ}(r)$ is a function related to the curvature of space, κ and the distance to origin $r$.
Then they proceed to talk about redshift of photons, according to the book, the photon travels in a null geodesic path, which results in $ds = 0$ without explanation. I really don't understand why, can anyone explain me why photons travel in a null geodesic path and why that results in $ds = 0$?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you familiar with special relativity? If so can you see why using the Minkowski metric for a photon's trajectory always gives $ds^2 = 0$?

yes, I got it, thank you!

In any metrics in general relativity, the photon geodesic is light-type by definition.
Consequently, the scalar product of an elementary displacement of the photon $ \overrightarrow{ds}.\overrightarrow{ds}=ds^2=0 $ , hence the name "null geodesic".
In other words, a light-type vector is orthogonal to itself which is the case for $ \overrightarrow{ds} $.
By the way, please note that $ ds\ne 0 $ (the norm of $ \overrightarrow{ds} $ is not zero).
Hoping to have answered your question,
Best regards.
